# Query for retrieving result in Normal forms

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I get a result like this?

EX:

```
id     |  name   |  locid
--------------------------
1      |  IND,UK |   1
       |  USA    |   2
       |  PAK    |   3
2      |  UAE    |   4
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please look at the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for information on how to ask questions here. As it stands, this question is lacking much of the information needed to be a good question. In SQL-related questions, specifying the table names and the column names (preferably with type information too) helps a lot. In this question, you really need to specify the structure of the source data; without that, we can only guess at what you're trying to deal with. Including the minimal data for the sample output helps too. (Claiming 3 days hardship is not good here!)

Comment: People here do want to help you, but your question is seriously lacking. You say you've spent three days trying to debug your problem. If you expect people to spend time helping you with your problem, how about spending 15 minutes to develop a test case, a sample table and data, along with the query text you've tried. Just sayin... http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2012/03/rubber-duck-problem-solving.html

Answer (score 3):

With what you give us to go on, just a sample of the desired resultset, I'm barely able to resist suggesting:

```
SELECT '1' AS `id`, 'IND,UK' AS `name`, '1' AS locid
UNION ALL SELECT '', 'USA', '2'
UNION ALL SELECT '', 'PAK', '3'
UNION ALL SELECT '2', 'UAE', '4'
```

---

Okay, so it turns out I wasn't able to resist suggesting it after all.

But I am pretty sure that doesn't answer the question you were asking.

I'm just guessing at your table structure here. But given:

```
CREATE TABLE mytable (id INT, locid INT, `name` VARCHAR(3));
INSERT INTO mytable VALUES (1,1,'IND'),(1,1,'UK'),(1,2,'USA'),(1,3,'PAK'),(2,4,'UAE');
```

This statement will return the specified result set:

```
SELECT IF(u.id_break=1,u.id,'') AS id
     , u.name
     , u.locid
  FROM ( SELECT IF(t.id = @last_id,0,1) AS id_break
              , @last_id := t.id AS id
              , t.locid
              , t.name
           FROM ( SELECT s.id, s.locid, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS `name`
                    FROM mytable s
                   GROUP BY s.id, s.locid
                   ORDER BY s.id, s.locid
                ) t
           JOIN (SELECT @last_id := NULL) i
          ORDER BY t.id, t.locid
       ) u
```

I'm just guessing here that the "missing" value in the column labeled `id` isn't really missing, but it's being suppressed, sort of a control break in the report.

I will note that the SQL statement I provided is NOT the normative pattern, since the result set of a query can be used as a row set for another query, the idea of "getting rid of" the repeated values on each row runs counter to the relational model.

Normally, this type of operation  (turning repeated values into a "control break" or a "heading") is typically handled at the report creation layer, and NOT in the SQL that pulls the result set.

If we don't need to eliminate the repeated id value on subsequent rows, the query is MUCH more straightforward:

```
SELECT t.id
     , t.locid
     , t.name
  FROM ( SELECT s.id, s.locid, GROUP_CONCAT(s.name) AS `name`
           FROM mytable s
          GROUP BY s.id, s.locid
          ORDER BY s.id, s.locid
       ) t
 ORDER BY t.id, t.locid
```

---

I'm not sure if any of this is helpful to you or not. As far as being an answer to your question, your question is way too vague.

Comment: +1 for effort above and beyond the call of duty!

Comment: @Jonathon, do you think I should have stopped after the first query? Thanks for your comment on the OP question.  Wisdom of the Ancients http://xkcd.com/979/

Comment: On the whole, I think the two part answer is better than just the first part.  The first answer is good, but a bit too smart-alecky to be the only answer (however justified).  But having to do the interpretation of the minimal information in the question was modestly hard work, and you did well with it.  As to the Wisdom of the Ancients: been there, done that! :D